# Getting Year value of present time zone in Android

Tags: android, time

**Android Programming** 
The following code `int year = new Time().year;`is returning value of year with default zone. So I am getting 1970 as the return value for year.
Whein I use the following constructor with field year `String zone=new Time().timezone;

int year = new Time(zone).year;`

I am getting the value for zone as ASIA/Calcutta but for year value I am still getting 1970 only. May I know why I am not getting the present year? Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `timezoneID` is `Asia/Calcutta`.If you are Asia/Calcutta timezone But if you are not and want to set just set Like  `TimeZone est = TimeZone.getTimeZone( "Asia/Calcutta" );`
 otherwise Use Below....

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String timezoneID = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID));
        int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        System.out.println(year);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you get an instance of calendar?

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
 int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

try like this..